# W3C Validation - Line Breaks with Ordered Lists

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I'm validating my website using the [W3C HTML validation](http://validator.w3.org/), and I'm getting errors for adding a line break in an ordered list.

E.g.:

```
<ol>
    <li>Stuff</li><br/>
    <li>Stuff2</li><br/>
</ol>
```

with successful validation would print

1. Stuff Stuff2

but it should be

1. Stuff
2. Stuff2

Without the line breaks it validates fine, but the list elements aren't on individual lines.
Is there a way that the site validates **WHILE** line breaking each `stuff` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel WOW on `<br/>` between `<li>`. `<li>` itself puts things in next line always..and you don't have anything in `<ol>` except `<li>`,

If you want some extra gap between `<li>'s` than use `margin` in CSS.

And how you say that:

> with successful validation would print
>
> 1. Stuff Stuff2

This will not going to happen with `<li>` though.

Comment: Seems to be ok now with a margin, don't know why <br/> tags can't just be added into <li> elements, is there a particular reason?

Comment: Actually, there is no reason, because HTML does not throw any error for that. Its just a case of _well structured document_

Comment: @Taffy, they are OK inside the li, but not inside the ul

Answer (score 1):

[You cannot have anything other than `<li>` inside a `<ol>` or `<ul>`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-ol-element.html#the-ol-element) Something in your CSS may be messing up your lists.

Comment: Yeah, as Asif said above, I changed the margin and that seems to have done it. Thank you :)